# How to separate servlet filter in a different application

Tags: java, spring-boot, middleware, servlet-filters

- I have a simple Springboot application which shows example of different restful Api's and i have connected the application with postgresql database.
- I made servlet filter as a middleware to capture the Http requests and responses. (currently just doing logging).
- But i want this filter to be separated in a different java application which acts as a middleware only. My whole application remains as it is and when i call any api it should just pass through the middleware application and then to the controller, currently middleware is in the same application.

> I haven't Configured anything to add this filter, if i want to specify different urls then only i have to configure it using a filterbean registration. So if in future i want to configure it i also want that in the middleware application only.

**Filter**

```
    @Component
    @WebFilter("/")
    public class MyFilter implements Filter {

    private final static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyFilter.class);

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        LOG.info("Request has come to filter");
        
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest)servletRequest;
        LOG.info("inside filter getting url:"+httpServletRequest.getRequestURI());
        
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest,servletResponse);
        
        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse)servletResponse;
        String gk = httpServletResponse.getHeader("GK");
        if(gk!=null){
            LOG.info(httpServletResponse.getHeader("Gk"));
        }
        
        LOG.info("Response has come to filter");
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String checkingFilter() {
        return "filter is working";
    }

    //get employees
    @GetMapping("employees")
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployee() {
        return this.employeeRepository.findAll();
    }

    //get employee by id
    @GetMapping("employees/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Employee> getEmployeeById(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long employeeId) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        Employee employee = employeeRepository.findById(employeeId).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Employee not found for this id :: " + employeeId));
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(employee);
    }

    //save employee
    @PostMapping("employees")
    public Employee createEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee) {
        return this.employeeRepository.save(employee);
    }

    @PostMapping("employees/all")
    public List<Employee> saveAllFresher(@RequestBody List<Employee> employeeList) {
        return this.employeeRepository.saveAll(employeeList);
    }


    //update employee
    @PutMapping("employees/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> updateEmployee(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long employeeId, @Valid @RequestBody Employee employeeDetails) throws ResourceNotFoundException {

        Employee employee = employeeRepository.findById(employeeId).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Employee not found for this id :: " + employeeId));
        employee.setEmail(employeeDetails.getEmail());
        employee.setFirstName(employeeDetails.getFirstName());
        employee.setLastName(employeeDetails.getLastName());
        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        responseHeaders.set("Gk",
                "Sde Intern");
        this.employeeRepository.save(employee);

        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .headers(responseHeaders)
                .body("Response with header using ResponseEntity");
    }

    //delete employee
    @DeleteMapping("employees/{id}")
    public Map<String, Boolean> deleteEmployee(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long employeeId) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        Employee employee = employeeRepository.findById(employeeId).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Employee not found for this id :: " + employeeId));
        this.employeeRepository.delete(employee);
        Map<String, Boolean> response = new HashMap<>();
        response.put("deleted", Boolean.TRUE);

        return response;
    }
}
```

I am making api calls through Postman.

Thanks in Advance, any help would be appreciated...

Comment: Why do want to do that? What is your usecase? And what exactly do you mean by "i want this filter to be separated in a different java application"? Usually you can run your Spring application as a web application inside a servlet server like Jetty or Tomcat. Or you can run it as its own process with an embedded servlet server. When you say "different java application" is it a different web application running inside the same servlet server along your main application? Or do you mean running in a separate process?

Comment: I want my Client and middleware in a different application, when client call for a request, it should first go to the middleware which is in a different application and then to the server. 
and wan to integrate both applications so that the middleware can be used.

Comment: Ok, but then you can't use Servlet Filters for that. You have to implement some kind of a proxy as a totally independent application. Servlet Filters can only be used inside the same application.

Comment: Thanks for clearing my doubt, really appreciated.